# Error running ASP.net CORE 1 project in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, web-deployment, asp.net-core-1.0

I've recently created a very simple ASP.net CORE 1 application using the default template.  I published it to a directory and created a new website in IIS for it.  Tested connecting to the site and it worked fine!  Great!

I took the same code and deployed it to my test server and get very different results.  I get an error:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
>
> Common causes of this issue:
>
> The application process failed to start The application process
>   started but then stopped The application process started but failed to
>   listen on the configured port

What could be the main difference between the two machines causing the problem?

Looking at the Windows event log, I see this error:

> Failed to start process with commandline '"dotnet" .\tester.dll',
>   ErrorCode = '0x80070002'.

Comment: Try to change your application pool to no managed code. You may need to make sure you have downloaded .net Core to your PC. Check this tutorial https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since dot net core RC1, you need to install the [windows server](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download) hosting library. (assuming IIS here)

It's not very well documented but after installing it, you just need to restart your IIS and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you install the DotNetCore WindowsHosting you have access to the internet because the installer download the VS 2015 resist x64 as dependency.

VS 2015 resist x64 - http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/c/b/8cb4af84-165e-4b36-978d-e867e07fc707/vc_redist.x64.exe